# Join Two Count(*) Tables with No Relation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, cross-join

I am trying to combine the results of a count(*) statement and a count(*) with a where clause on a SQL Server Table into a single table.

I have a union statement that bring together the two queries one of top of another.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].asma a
where [MLR] in ('y')) l
union
SELECT count (*) as 'Total' FROM [dbo].asma]
```

[image: Union Return]

[This post](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/766095/Join-two-table-without-common-field) of solutions I looked at, but couldn't piece together a solution that would present these side by side.  How would you do this?

What I need is this output:

[image]

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Comment: Your top query, shouldn't that by `select count(*)`?

Comment: A UNION's two selects must return the same number of columns

Comment: @sgeddes yes i shortened the query and removed that, i will re-add

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do *conditional* aggregation instead :

```
select sum(case when MLR = 'y' then 1 else 0 end) as Active, count(*) as Total
from dbo.asma a;
```

Comment: or `count(case when MLR = 'y' then 1 else null end)`